# At least one perfect square in $[S_n,S_{n+1}]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

Given $\{a_n\}$ a sequence of real numbers such that $a_1 > 1$ and $a_{n+1}-a_n\geq 2$, with $S_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$, prove that for any $n\geq 3$, there is at least one perfect square in the range $[S_n, S_{n+1}]$.

---

I was thinking that $a_{n+1}\ge 2+a_n \ge 4+a_{n-1}\geq ... \ge 2n+a_1>2n+1$.
And this implies $S_{n+1}-S_n=a_{n+1}>2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2$. So at least one of $n^2$ or $(n+1)^2$ si between $S_{n}$ and $S_{n+1}$.

Is this reasoning correct? I don't think it is. How to prove the problem then?

Comment: The last part of the reasoning is wrong.  Just because $S_{n+1}-S_n>(n+1)^2-n^2$, it doesn't follow that there's a square between $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$.  Take $n=6$.  It's not true that there's a square between any two numbers more than $13$ apart.  Try $82$ and $97$.

Comment: @saulspatz, thanks, I suspected so. Maybe assume $m^2 < S_n<S_{n+1}<(m+1)^2$ and try to find a contradiction?

Comment: That looks more promising, though I must say I haven't solved the problem yet.

Comment: where does the question come from?

Comment: @punctureddusk, a local pre-olympiad test at my school from 2001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_1 \geq 0$ and $a_{n+1} - a_n \geq 2$. Define $S_n = a_1 + \cdots  + a_n$. We will show that $[S_n, S_{n+1}]$ contains a perfect square for all $n \geq 1$.

**Lemma.** Let $0 \leq x < y$ be real numbers with $y -x \geq 2\sqrt x + 1$. Then $[x, y]$ contains a perfect square.

*Proof.* Let $n^2 \geq 0$ be the largest square with $n^2 \leq x$. Then
$$x < (n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 \leq x + 2 \sqrt x + 1 \leq y \,. \qquad\square$$

So suffices to show that $a_{n+1} \geq 2 \sqrt{S_n} + 1$. I.e. that $4 S_n \leq (a_{n+1} - 1)^2$. We prove this by induction.

For $n = 1$ this follows from
$$(a_2-1)^2 \geq (a_1+1)^2 \geq (2\sqrt{a_1})^2 = 4 a_1 \,.$$
Take $n \geq 1$, and suppose
$$4 S_n \leq (a_{n+1} - 1)^2 \,.$$
Add $4a_{n+1}$ to both sides to obtain
$$4S_{n+1} \leq (a_{n+1} + 1)^2 \,.$$
Then use that $a_{n+1} +1 \leq a_{n+2} - 1$ to get
$$4S_{n+1} \leq (a_{n+2} - 1)^2 \,.$$
The induction is complete.

Comment: $a_{n+1} \geq 2 \sqrt{S_n} + 1$, here $S_{n+1}$ corresponds to $y$ and $S_{n}$ corresponds to $x$, that took me a bit of time to understand.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of contradiction assume that there exists some $n$ such that $[S_n, S_{n+1}]$ does not contain a perfect square. That means there is some positive integer $p$ such that:

$$p^2 < S_n<S_{n+1} < (p+1)^2$$

We then have:

$$a_{n+1} = S_{n+1}-S_n<(p+1)^2-p^2=2p+1$$

That implies $a_n \leq a_{n+1}-2<2p-1$ and generally $a_{n-k} < 2p-(2k+1)$ for any $k\leq n-1$. Summing up all these inequalities we get:

$$S_n=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n<\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[2p-(2k+1)\right]=2np-n^2$$

Therefore:

$$2np-n^2>S_n>p^2\Rightarrow (p-n)^2 < 0$$

which is obviously a contradiction.

Comment: I've always loved the simplicity of proof by contradiction!! great job man